# Workflow update after edit not launching second time

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I created a list workflow in sharepoint designer 2013 to update several other lists after I edit a list.  It works the first time the record is changed but never again. I have deleted the record and inserted a new one and then edited it again and it always works the first time only. I have added several logs to track the WF and it shows me that it does not start. Can someone help.

Comment: Your workflow fires on which event? like item created, Updated

Comment: Could you please share the logs or screenshot where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" checkbox in the workflow's page?
[image]